# ignore text because of echo´ing image?

Tags: php

I´m drawing an image in PHP from another website, which works. And I´m getting info and from a webpage, which is working. But together it isn´t and only shows the image.
If I cut the picture part and put it at the end it gives an error.
(Use for example nickname Mazey if you need to check out how that JSON page look like)
Has it to do with combining file get contents and my curl function?

```
<?php

$profPic  = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'https://api.kag2d.com/player/'.urlencode( $_GET['nickname'] ).'/avatar/s' ) );
if ( $profPic ) {
  if ( isset( $profPic->small ) ) {
      $profPic  = $profPic->small;
      $extension  = strtolower( pathinfo( $profPic, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
      $content  = file_get_contents( $profPic );
  if ( $content ) {
    header( "Content-type: image/".$extension );
    echo $content;
    exit();
  }
}
  } else {
    echo "error";
    }
  $stats = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.kag2d.com/player/'.urlencode(    $_GET['nickname'] ).'/status' ));
  if ( $stats ) {
    if ( isset ( $stats->playerInfo ) ) {
      echo $stats->playerInfo->username;
  } else {
    echo 'Error';
    }
  } else {
    echo 'Error';
  }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to return two different HTTP responses in the same file.  If you read the section for images, it does an exit() after printing the image data.  This why it stops processing.

When I ran the URLs included in the source, the username returned is the same as the value in the  $_GET['nickname'].  Do you actually need to look this value up?  It would work if you just returned the image.

*A solution* is to return a JSON document like your third party server is doing, and embed all the information in this.  It is legal HTML to have [image data as an URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), so the entire thing could be returned as single JSON document.  HTML based example from the RFC2397

```
<IMG SRC="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhMAAwAPAAAAAAAP///ywAAAA
AMAAwAAAC8IyPqcvt3wCcDkiLc7C0qwyGHhSWpjQu5yqmCYsapyuvUUlvONmOZt
fzgFzByTB10QgxOR0TqBQejhRNzOfkVJ+5YiUqrXF5Y5lKh/DeuNcP5yLWGsEbt
LiOSpa/TPg7JpJHxyendzWTBfX0cxOnKPjgBzi4diinWGdkF8kjdfnycQZXZeYG
ejmJlZeGl9i2icVqaNVailT6F5iJ90m6mvuTS4OK05M0vDk0Q4XUtwvKOzrcd3i
q9uisF81M1OIcR7lEewwcLp7tuNNkM3uNna3F2JQFo97Vriy/Xl4/f1cf5VWzXy
ym7PHhhx4dbgYKAAA7" ALT="Larry">
```

Unlike email, noone seems to be developing multi-part mime responses inside HTTP. I did a quick google, but no useful results.

Comment: I don´t need to look the username itself up, I could also use Role if you wanted that, but I took it to test it too (as I need to test if I can connect properly).

Comment: Sorry, italic text doesn't seem to be rendering correctly "A solution".

Comment: looks like i am now, will post if worked + choose your answer.